# Question about the IEEEtran.cls font in Texstudio

Tags: fonts, ieeetran

#### Environment

- TeXstudio: 4.6.3
- Qt: 6.5.2 R
- OS: Windows 11
- TeX distribution:  texlive2023

#### Expected behavior

I am using the very common class file [bare_jrnl.tex](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bare_jrnl.tex) to finish my journal paper [IEEEtran – Document class for IEEE Transactions journals and conferences](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/?lang=en). The default font is **Times New Roman**, and it display correctly on Texworks or Overleaf (figure attached below).

**I WANT THE TIMES FONT.**
[image: Quicker_20231019_133509]

#### Actual behavior

But when the files are opened in Texstudio, the default font is **Computer Modern**. It is certain that the original class file [IEEEtran.cls](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran.cls) contain the font definition lines, which never be changed:

```
% The IEEE uses Times Roman font, so we'll default to Times.
% These three commands make up the entire times.sty package.
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
```

**BUT IN TEXSTUDIO, IT IS COMPUTER MODERN FONT.**
[image: Quicker_20231019_133550]

#### How to reproduce

Just run this file [bare_jrnl.tex](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bare_jrnl.tex).

**BUT IN TEXSTUDIO, IT IS COMPUTER MODERN FONT.**

**I WANT THE TIMES FONT.**

Comment: texstudio is just the editor so  has no effect here, check the log file of your run for the full path to the class you may have a second copy with different settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not mention it but your image just half shows one line of console output showing that you used xelatex.

the document is not set up for xelatex, if you use it you get multiple warnings that you did not show, ending in

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

and in fact basically none of the font selections work and you get the default xelatex latin modern fonts.

The choice of editor does not matter but you need to use pdflatex not xelatex.

You could have made this easier to spot:

[image]

please always show log output as text not as an image.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply! I am just a new user to TeX and appreciate your patience.